# How to mock a module function inside a callback with Sinon.JS?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, sinon, stub

I have the following Javascript code:

```
import Notifications from 'notification-system';

export class DocumentParameters {
  handleUpload() {
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      Notifications.success();
    });
  }
}
```

`notification-system` is some module I installed with npm.

I would like to mock `Notifications.success` in this unit test:

```
import Notifications from 'notification-system';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { DocumentParameters } from './document';

describe('handleUpload()', () => {
  it('should upload and create a success notification', (done) => {
    const success = sinon.stub(Notifications, 'success');
    const documentParameters = new DocumentParameters();

    documentParameters.handleUpload().then(() => {
      expect(success.callCount).to.equal(1);
      done();
    });

    success.restore();
  });
});
```

This unit test fails because the stub is never called: `success.callCount` is 0.

**My solution :**

```
import Notifications from 'notification-system';

export class DocumentParameters {
  handleUpload() {
    const success = Notifications.success;
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      success();
    });
  }
}
```

So the stub is working outside the callback but not inside. However, I was told that it is a bad practice to update the original code to get a working unit test.

Do you know a solution which does not imply to change the original code?

Answer (score 0):

Since someone upvoted my question:

The issue here is that I restore the stub `success` too quickly.
The stub should be restored inside the promise .then() instead.

The following code would work:

```
import Notifications from 'notification-system';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { DocumentParameters } from './document';

describe('handleUpload()', () => {
  it('should upload and create a success notification', (done) => {
    const success = sinon.stub(Notifications, 'success');
    const documentParameters = new DocumentParameters();

    documentParameters.handleUpload().then(() => {
      expect(success.callCount).to.equal(1);
      success.restore();
      done();
    });
  });
});
```